# Error while sending email on iOS app with unity

Tags: c#, c++, ios, email, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a school project and I'm trying to log data that is stored from a game that I made in unity.

My problem is that I want to email the data true the app. Everything works fine, email is sending with the data etc. But when I build the app to an iOS device it is not sending the email.

I do not have any errors in unity but I get this error in Xcode when I build the app.See the error below. I hope someone can help me.

Greetings,

Georgi Iliev

```
MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Default constructor not found...ctor() of System.Net.Configuration.MailSettingsSectionGroup'.
  at Mono.Security.Authenticode.AuthenticodeBase.GetSecurityEntry () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Configuration.Configuration.GetSectionGroupInstance (System.Configuration.SectionGroupInfo group) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSectionGroupCollection.get_Item (System.String name) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Configuration.Configuration.GetSection (System.String path) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection (System.String configKey) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection (System.String sectionName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient..ctor (System.String host, Int32 port) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoGmail.Start () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

(Filename: currently not available on il2cpp Line: -1)
```

added @programmers solution and got a new mixed error.

```
MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Default constructor not found...ctor() of System.Net.Configuration.MailSettingsSectionGroup'.
  at StartMenu.CloseApp () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, Boolean nonPublic) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Configuration.ConfigInfo.CreateInstance () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Collections.Generic.Comparer`1[T].get_Default () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Configuration.Configuration.GetSectionGroupInstance (System.Configuration.SectionGroupInfo group) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSectionGroupCollection.get_Item (System.String name) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Configuration.Configuration.GetSection (System.String path) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection (System.String configKey) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.MonoTODOAttribute..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection (System.String sectionName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient..ctor (System.String host, Int32 port) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient..ctor (System.String host) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono_Gmail.Start () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Array.GetGenericValueImpl[T] (Int32 pos, .T& value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Array.GetGenericValueImpl[T] (Int32 pos, .T& value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Array.GetGenericValueImpl[T] (Int32 pos, .T& value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Array.GetGenericValueImpl[T] (Int32 pos, .T& value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
System.Array:GetGenericValueImpl(Int32, T&)
System.Array:GetGenericValueImpl(Int32, T&)
System.Array:GetGenericValueImpl(Int32, T&)
System.Array:GetGenericValueImpl(Int32, T&)

(Filename: currently not available on il2cpp Line: -1)
```

Comment: can you please, fix the formatting?

Comment: And post a snippet of the code around the error. Also, compile your code for debug and then try again (so that the exception can be more useful to you and others)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/il2cpp-crashes-when-using-smtpclient) in **IL2CPP**.  Unity does not have any plan to fix this issue any time soon because there is a temporary solution to fix it.

In your **link.xml**, add the following to it.

```
<linker>
<assembly fullname="System">
<type fullname="System.Net.Configuration.MailSettingsSectionGroup" preserve="all"/>
<type fullname="System.Net.Configuration.SmtpSection" preserve="all"/>
<type fullname="System.Net.Configuration.SmtpNetworkElement" preserve="all"/>
</assembly>
</linker>
```

It is basically telling Xcode to not strip these mail stuff out.

If you don't have **link.xml**, create it and put the code above in it then place the file in the Asset folder. Rebuild the project.

**EDIT**:

According to a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36087436/error-while-sending-email-on-ios-app-with-unity/36090450?noredirect=1#comment80411073_36090450) below, it is now required to add the line below too:

```
<type fullname="System.Net.Configuration.SmtpSpecifiedPickupDirectoryElement" preserve="all"/>
```

Comment: But if I do this would it still be possible to send the data I want true email?

Comment: ?? This will fix the error you have in xCode. Assuming the code you have works on windows, it should work on iOS.

Comment: Never tested in on Windows, it works on a MacBook Pro. Sorry for not adding that to the question information.

Comment: Yes it should work on iOS if it works on Mac too. Just do what I posted above before making further comments.

Comment: could you look once more at the question please ?

Comment: I fixed the second error. But i never made my own xml file. Where to i put the file to strip out the email stuff?

And im sorry that it takes so long to answer i had a week off.

Comment: You did not fix any error. `Default constructor not found...ctor() of System.Net.Configuration.MailSettingsSectionGroup` is still there in your second error and there is no way you can fix it without doing what I mentioned above. All you have to do is create a link.xml file, put the code in my answer in it then put the file in the Asset folder in Unity. That's it.

Comment: Thanks man everything worked. I did exactly what you told me to I made a link.xml and added it to my assets folder! <3

Comment: Since you answered this post it is now also required to add this to the XML to make it work : `<type fullname="System.Net.Configuration.SmtpSpecifiedPickupDirectoryElement" preserve="all"/>`. Tested with Unity 2017.1 on iOS 11.

Comment: @Whatever Thanks for the heads up. Modified answer to include that.